# Proving that ${\mathscr{V}}^s( E \cup \widetilde{E})< 2 \leq {\mathscr{V}}^s( E ) + {\mathscr{V}}^s( \widetilde{E} )\quad$

Tags: analysis, fractals

For $E$ a (totally) bounded subset of $X$ and $s>0$, the
Hewitt-Stromberg pre-measure is defined as follows,
$$
 \overline{\mathscr{V}}^s(E)=\limsup_{\delta\to0} M_\delta(E) \;(2\delta)^s,
$$
where the  packing
number $M_\delta(E)$ of $E$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
M_\delta(E) = & \sup\Biggl\{\sharp\{I\}\; \Bigl|\; \Big(B(x_i,
\delta)
\Big)_{i\in I} \; \text{is a family of closed  balls}  \\
&\qquad\qquad\quad\text{with}\; x_i \in E \; \text{and}\; B(x_i,
\delta)\cap B(x_j, \delta)=\emptyset\; \text{for}\; i\neq j\Biggl\}.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Now, we define the  $s$-dimensional Hewitt-Stromberg
measure as follows
$$
{\mathscr{V}}^s(E)=\inf\left\{\sum_i
\overline{\mathscr{V}}^s(E_i)\;\Big|\;\;E\subseteq\bigcup_i
E_i\right\}.
$$

We will construct  two
positively separated sets $E$ and $\widetilde{E}$, and show that
there exists $s>0$ such that $${\mathscr{V}}^s( E \cup
\widetilde{E})\neq {\mathscr{V}}^s( E ) + {\mathscr{V}}^s(
\widetilde{E} ).$$

First, we consider the following two IFS's on
$[0,1]$, namely
$$S=(S_1,S_2)\quad\text{ where}\;\; S_1(x)=\frac x3 \;\;\text{and}\;\; S_2(x)=\frac x3+\frac
23,$$ and $$T=(T_1,T_2)\quad\text{where}\;\; T_1(x)=\frac
x6\;\;\text{and}\;\; T_2(x)=\frac x6+\frac 56.$$

Next, construct the sets $E$ and $F$ as follows. Fix a sequence
$n_1,n_2,n_3,...$ of positive integers. We construct the set $E$ as
follows. Let
\begin{eqnarray*}
E_1 &=& {   S_{i_{1,1}}\circ   S_{i_{1,2}}\circ\ldots \circ
S_{i_{1,n_1}}([0,1])    },\\ E_2 &=& {
   S_{i_{1,1}}\circ   S_{i_{1,2}}\circ\ldots \circ S_{i_{1,n_1}}\circ T_{j_{1,1}}\circ   T_{j_{1,2}}\circ\ldots\circ
   T_{j_{1,n_1}}([0,1])},\\
E_3 &=& {
   S_{i_{1,1}}\circ  S_{i_{1,2}}\circ\ldots \circ S_{i_{1,n_1}}
   \circ T_{j_{1,1}}\circ T_{j_{1,2}}\circ\ldots\circ T_{j_{1,n_1}}\circ S_{i_{2,1}}\circ  S_{i_{2,2}}\circ\ldots\circ S_{i_{2,n_2}}([0,1])
   },\\
 E_4 &=&    S_{i_{1,1}}\circ  S_{i_{1,2}}\circ\ldots \circ S_{i_{1,n_1}}
   \circ T_{j_{1,1}}\circ T_{j_{1,2}}\circ\ldots\circ
   T_{j_{1,n_1}}\circ S_{i_{2,1}}\circ  S_{i_{2,2}}\circ\ldots\circ
   S_{i_{2,n_2}}\circ\\&&\qquad\quad\qquad\quad\qquad\quad\qquad\quad\qquad\quad\qquad\quad\qquad\quad\qquad\quad\qquad\quad
   T_{j_{2,1}}\circ  T_{j_{2,2}}\circ\ldots\circ
   T_{j_{2,n_2}}([0,1]),\\
&\vdots&
\end{eqnarray*}
where the indices $i_{1,1},...,i_{1,n_1}...$ takes on all values of
$1,2.$ Continue like this, and put
$$E  = \bigcap_n    \bigcup_{I\in E_n}  I.$$

Next, construct the set $F$ as follows. Let
\begin{eqnarray*}
F_1 &=& {   T_{j_{1,1}}\circ T_{j_{1,2}}\circ\ldots \circ
T_{j_{1,n_1}}([0,1])},\\
 F_2& =& {
T_{j_{1,1}}\circ T_{j_{1,2}}\circ\ldots \circ T_{j_{1,n_1}}\circ
S_{i_{1,1}}\circ S_{i_{1,2}}\circ\ldots\circ S_{i_{1,n_1}}([0,1])
  },\\
F_3& = &{ T_{j_{1,1}}\circ T_{j_{1,2}}\circ\ldots\circ
T_{j_{1,n_1}}\circ S_{i_{1,1}}\circ S_{i_{1,2}}\circ\ldots\circ
S_{i_{1,n_1}}\circ T_{j_{2,1}}\circ T_{j_{2,2}}\circ\ldots\circ
T_{j_{2,n_2}}([0,1])
  },\\
F_4 &=&T_{j_{1,1}}\circ T_{j_{1,2}}\circ\ldots\circ
T_{j_{1,n_1}}\circ S_{i_{1,1}}\circ S_{i_{1,2}}\circ\ldots\circ
S_{i_{1,n_1}}\circ T_{j_{2,1}}\circ T_{j_{2,2}}\circ\ldots\circ
T_{j_{2,n_2}}\circ\\&&\qquad\quad\qquad\quad\qquad\quad\qquad\quad\qquad\quad\qquad\quad\quad\qquad\qquad\quad\qquad
 S_{i_{2,1}}\circ S_{i_{2,2}} \circ\ldots\circ
S_{i_{2,n_2}}([0,1]),\\
&\vdots&
\end{eqnarray*}
where the indices $i_{1,1},...,i_{1,n_1}...$ takes on all values of
$1,2.$ Continue like this, and put
$$ F  = \bigcap_n    \bigcup_{J\in F_n}  J.$$

Now, it is clear that the sets $E$ and  $\widetilde{E}:=F+2$ are
positively separated, and if we choose the integers
$n_1,n_2,n_3,...$ are sufficiently large, then
$${\mathscr{V}}^s( E  \cup \widetilde{E})< 2 \leq   {\mathscr{V}}^s( E )
  + {\mathscr{V}}^s( \widetilde{E} )\quad\text{for} \quad s=\frac{2\log2}{\log 3+\log 6}.$$

I need the proof of the last claimed inequalities????